# Implement CXF client to read LIST from a REST server

Tags: web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, cxf, cxf-client

I am trying to implement a rest web service using Apache CXF and I want to return list of object as a response from server. So i have used generic entity to wrap my list on a server and everything is fine when I enter path from browser. It prints XML representation of object because I have used Jackson JAX-B but when i try to use JAX-RS client. I am getting an exception.

> Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: Problem with reading the data, class XYZ, ContentType: */*.
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.reportMessageHandlerProblem(ResponseImpl.java:433)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.doReadEntity(ResponseImpl.java:378)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.readEntity(ResponseImpl.java:325)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.readEntity(ResponseImpl.java:313)
>       at XYZ.ABC()
>       at XYZ.ABC()
>   Caused by: javax.ws.rs.core.NoContentException: Message body is empty
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.reportEmptyContentLength(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:276)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider.readFrom(JAXBElementProvider.java:166)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBodyReader(JAXRSUtils.java:1325)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.doReadEntity(ResponseImpl.java:369)
>       ... 4 more

I have written a following client code to get data from server
        `final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget webTarget = client.target(URI.create(PATH));
        Response response = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get();
        List<ABC> obj = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<ABC>>              (ABC.class){});`

But Apart from it I have tried many code to implement CXF client and get data from server but I am getting a same exception almost all the time. I have tried JAXRSCLIENTFactory also to implement client but the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem in unmarshalling using the CXF client. Here is how I did it:

1. Read the response into a String.
2. Used Gson to convert from string to list of objects.

Note: You will need a wrapper class for your list of objects.

### Example:

If the server returns a list of products, Here is how to unmarshall the list:

### Create a wrapper class

```
public class ProductList {  

private List<Product> products;

public List<Product> getProducts() {
    return products;
}

public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
    this.products = products;
}

}
```

Code to unmarshall

```
String responseBody = response.readEntity(String.class);
ProductList productList = new Gson().fromJson(responseBody, ProductList.class);
if(productList.getProducts() != null)
    return productList.getProducts();
```